# Weird stuff with curried function

Tags: scala, currying, control-flow

I have this weird situation that I don't understand. I'm reading "Programming in Scala" book, Ch. 9.

Let's say I have a curried function:

```
def withThis(n:Int)(op:Int=>Unit){
      println("Before")
      op(n);
      println("After")
}
```

When I call it with one argument inside a special curly-syntax it works as expected:

```
withThis(5){
   (x) => {println("Hello!"); println(x); }
}
// Outputs
Before
Hello!
5
After
```

However, if I put two statements, I get something wierd:

```
withThis(5){
     println("Hello!")
     println(_)
}
// Outputs
Hello!
Before
5
After
```

How come the "Hello!" gets printed before "Before" and then "5" is printed inside? Am I crazy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your last code example should be rewritten as follows to produce the expected result:

```
withThis(5) { x =>
     println("Hello!")
     println(x)
}
```

Otherwise, your example is equivalent to

```
withThis(5) {
     println("Hello!")
     (x: Int) => println(x)
}
```

as the placeholder `_` will be expanded to bind as tightly as possible in a non-degenerated way (i.e., it wouldn't expand to `println(x => x)`).

The other thing to note is that a block always returns its last value. In your example, the last value is actually `(x: Int) => println(x)`.

Comment: But println(x => x) is not even correct syntax. In any case - I understand what println(_) does - I was more confusing as to this "block" business.

Comment: The syntax is correct. It wouldn't compile in this case because of the missing parameter type, but would work if the compiler could infer it. Trivial example: `def doit(f: Int => Int) = (); doit(x => x)`

Comment: I know that it is equivalent "(x: Int) => println(x)", my question is why does it actually execute println first. I guess you answered with "block always returns the last value". Does this mean that blocks are not lazily evaluated?

Comment: You're right, blocks are not lazily evaluated in this context.

Answer (score 3):

In your second example the part in curlies: `{ println("Hello!"); println(_) }` is a block which prints "Hello!" and returns a curried `println`.  Imagine it simplified as `{ println("Hello!"); 5 }`, a block which prints "Hello!" and returns 5.

Comment: I don't think I got to "blocks" part in the book yet. That is why I am confused probably.

Comment: So there is no way to make it work as expected in the second example? I tried with by-name parameters - but they don't take an argument.

Comment: Just to be picky: the block doesn't return a “curried `println`”, but an anonymous function with one argument that calls println with the argument it gets.

Comment: I suspect you get it. "Block" is just lambda with anonymous arguments. But yours is being parsed as `() => () => Unit`, evaluated, and its curried result passed to `withThis(5)`. Did you try JP's `x =>` at the top of your block? That should prevent parsing it as `() => …`. The lesson for me is be wary using inferred arguments.